# How to put elements between two divs (CSS, HTML)

Tags: html, css

I need to do something like this.
Between to divs, I have two buttons, always locate in
the middle of the crossline.
By the way, I need to show this in different devices,
so I can't use

```
position: absolute
```

Please help, thank you!Here is my code:

HTML

```
        <div class="login-back-up">
        </div>
        <div class="login-back-down">
          <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
            <a href="#" class="button">button1</a>
            <a href="#" class="button">button2</a>
          </p>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.login-back-up{
width:100%;
height:80%
}
.login-back-down{
width:100%;
height:20%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add your code please. You can put them at the very top of the yellow `div` and use negative `margin-top`

Comment: Shouldn't `height` in `.login-back-down` be 20%?

Comment: Can you change HTML layout? Like add, remove, or change tags (elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

**1. Change both HTML and CSS** (if you are writing your page this is the best option)

Let's look at what we have:

```css
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%; /*You were missing ; at the end of this line*/
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-back-up">
</div>
<div class="login-back-down">
    <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
        <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
        <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
    </p>
</div>
```

When you run this code you just get `B̲u̲t̲t̲o̲n̲ B̲u̲t̲t̲o̲n̲`. That is because we use percentages (%) when defining width and height in CSS so I will add div tag and put all HTML code in it and I'll specify width and height of that div (with pixel values). Also, I'll add `background-color` attributes to `.login-back-up` and `.login-back-down` in CSS so we can see them.

```css
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
  Div <!--I added this to match picture of example from OP-->
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </p>
      Div <!--I added this to match picture of example from OP-->
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that div `.login-back-up` and `.login-back-down` have a hole between them. It is because div `.login-back-down` contains p tag which has margin by default so I'll replace p tag with div. I'll also style the buttons (add background color, padding, margin, color, and remove underlining) and set the color in HTML to white (because all text is white in this example).

```css
body {
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* this is some version of green*/
    text-decoration: none; /* this is to remove underlining*/
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
    padding: 10px 10px; /* this adds (green) space around text */
    margin: 0px 10px; /* this adds space around buttons */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
  Div
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      <div class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </div>
      Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Now to position buttons we are going to: put div `.buttons-row hr-login-button-row` out of div `login-back-down` and inside another (container) div. Container div will be between divs `login-back-up` and `login-back-down` so we'll just need to set the `height` of container div to `0`.

```css
body {
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* this is some version of green*/
    text-decoration: none; /* this is to remove underlining*/
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
    padding: 10px 10px; /* this adds (green) space around text */
    margin: 0px 10px; /* this adds space around buttons */
}
.container {
    height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
      Div
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      Div
  </div>
</div>
```

All that is left is to center elements (text and buttons). I'll do this by using display as flex. For tags which children you want to center you add `display: flex;` in CSS. Also, if you want to center them horizontally you add `justify-content: center;` in CSS and if you want to center them vertically you add `align-items: center;`

```css
body {
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* this is some version of green*/
    text-decoration: none; /* this is to remove underlining*/
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
    padding: 10px 10px; /* this adds (green) space around text */
    margin: 0px 10px; /* this adds space around buttons */
}
.container {
    height: 0px;
    /* this is to align buttons in center */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    height: 0px;
}
.login-back-up, .login-back-down{
    /* this is to align text in center,
    you don't have to use if you dont need
    text centered inside div */
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
      Div
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      Div
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. Change only CSS** (Use this option only if you can't change HTML)

I'll start with the second code snippet from option 1. (one in which is added div `main` and `background-color` attributes.

```css
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

First I'll remove hole between divs `.login-back-up` and `.login-back-down` by setting `margin` of p tag `buttons-row` to `0`. I also add styling for buttons just like in option 1., add text to div tags with CSS and set color of text in body to white.

```css
body {
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
}
.buttons-row {
    margin: 0;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* this is some version of green*/
    text-decoration: none; /* this is to remove underlining*/
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
    padding: 10px 10px; /* this adds (green) space around text */
    margin: 0px 10px; /* this adds space around buttons */
}
.login-back-up:after, .login-back-down:after {
    /* this is to add text to div, you
    don't have to use if you dont need
    text inside div */
    position: absolute; /* this is so text can be centered later*/
    content:'Div'; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now we need to center text and buttons but without changing HTML. I'll do this also by using display as flex like in option 1.

```css
body {
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
    /* this is to align text in center,
    you don't have to use if you dont need
    text centered inside div */
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
    display: flex; /* this is to align both text and buttons in center */
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
.buttons-row {
    margin: 0;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* this is some version of green*/
    text-decoration: none; /* this is to remove underlining*/
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
    padding: 10px 10px; /* this adds (green) space around text */
    margin: 0px 10px; /* this adds space around buttons */
}
.login-back-up:after, .login-back-down:after {
    /* this is to add text to div, you
    don't have to use if you dont need
    text inside div */
    position: absolute; /* this is so text can be centered later*/
    content:'Div'; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only problem is that buttons are centered in `.login-back-down` div, but we will fix that by adding negative top value to `.buttons-row`.

```css
body {
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 340px;
}
.login-back-up {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: #00A1FF;
    /* this is to align text in center,
    you don't have to use if you dont need
    text centered inside div */
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
.login-back-down {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: #F9BA00;
    display: flex; /* this is to align both text and buttons in center */
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
.buttons-row {
    margin: 0;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* this is some version of green*/
    text-decoration: none; /* this is to remove underlining*/
    color: white; /* text color is white*/
    padding: 10px 10px; /* this adds (green) space around text */
    margin: 0px 10px; /* this adds space around buttons */
}
.login-back-up:after, .login-back-down:after {
    /* this is to add text to div, you
    don't have to use if you dont need
    text inside div */
    position: absolute; /* this is so text can be centered later*/
    content:'Div'; 
}
.buttons-row {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="login-back-up">
  </div>
  <div class="login-back-down">
      <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--I change it to Button because that-->
          <a href="#" class="button">Button</a> <!--is on picture of example from OP-->
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` could be the simpliest way:

```css
.login-back-up {
  background: rgb(0, 161, 255)
}

.login-back-down {
  background: rgb(249, 187, 0)
}

.button {
  background: rgb(96, 217, 55);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

div {
  min-height: 4em;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}

.buttons-row {
  line-height: 0;/* here is maybe the magic you looked for*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-back-up">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="login-back-down">
  <p class="buttons-row hr-login-button-row">
    <a href="#" class="button">button1</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">button2</a>
  </p>
  <p>next content below</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can add `postion: absolute` and still display on variety of devices.

```css
#divs {
  position: relative;
}

#divs>div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#div-a {
  background: #03A9F4;
}

#div-b {
  background: #FFCA28;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -75vh 10vw 0 10vw;
}

#buttons>button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #69F0AE;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="divs">
  <div id="div-a">Div</div>
  <div id="div-b">Div</div>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="button-a">Button 1</button>
  <button id="button-b">Button 2</button>
</div>
```